# stargazer omits some coefficients I did not specify

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

It's kind of wired. stargazer omitted some coefficients which I did not specify. In contrast, I would like those coefficients presented in the output table. Below are the codes.

First, here is the code for the output of the entire model without any omit.

```
stargazer(modeltt,modelintt,modelintt1,modelintt2,modelintt3, 
          title = "Panel data with averaged climate variables part two",
          model.names = F, object.names = F, dep.var.caption = "Yield", 
          dep.var.labels.include = F,
          column.labels = c("Only Ozone","Ozone and SPEI","Ozone and tem", 
          "Ozone and preci","All together"),
          dep.var.labels = "Yield", digits = 3,
          align = T, no.space = T, column.sep.width = "3pt", 
          omit.stat = "f", header = F)
```

The code above generated the Latex code below.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Panel data with averaged climate variables part two} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{3pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yield} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 tm\_fall & -0.007 \\ 
  & (0.016) \\ 
  I(tm\_fall$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & 0.0001 \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  tm\_winter & 0.022^{***} \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  I(tm\_winter$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & -0.0003^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  tm\_spring & 0.042^{***} \\ 
  & (0.011) \\ 
  I(tm\_spring$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & -0.0005^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  pc\_fall & 0.008^{**} \\ 
  & (0.003) \\ 
  I(pc\_fall$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & -0.0005^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  pc\_winter & 0.006^{**} \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
  I(pc\_winter$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & -0.0002^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  pc\_spring & -0.012^{*} \\ 
  & (0.007) \\ 
  I(pc\_spring$\hat{\mkern6mu}$2) & -0.001^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  oz\_spring & -0.005 \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  I(oz\_spring \textasteriskcentered  sp\_spring) & -0.0002^{*} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  I(tm\_spring \textasteriskcentered  oz\_spring) & 0.00003 \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  I(pc\_spring \textasteriskcentered  oz\_spring) & 0.001^{***} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  lt & 0.005^{***} \\ 
  & (0.001) \\ 
  qt & 0.0001^{**} \\ 
  & (0.00004) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4,960} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.127} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.031} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Then here I specified some coefficients to be omitted. In the end, stargazer omitted more than I specified.

```
stargazer(modeltt,modelintt,modelintt1,modelintt2,modelintt3, 
          title = "Panel data with averaged climate variables part two",
          model.names = F, object.names = F, dep.var.caption = "Yield", 
          dep.var.labels.include = F,
          omit = c("tm_fall","I(tm_fall^2)","tm_winter","I(tm_winter^2)",
                  "tm_spring","I(tm_spring^2)","pc_fall","I(pc_fall^2)",
                  "pc_winter","I(pc_winter^2)","pc_spring","I(pc_spring^2)",
                  "lt","qt"),
          column.labels = c("Only Ozone","Ozone and SPEI","Ozone and tem", 
          "Ozone and preci","All together"),
          dep.var.labels = "Yield", digits = 3,
          align = T, no.space = T, column.sep.width = "3pt", 
          omit.stat = "f", header = F)
```

The code above generated Latex code below.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Panel data with averaged climate variables part two} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{3pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yield} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 oz\_spring & -0.005 \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  I(oz\_spring \textasteriskcentered  sp\_spring) & -0.0002^{*} \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4,960} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.127} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.031} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Someone can explain this for me???

Comment: Hard to read the latex command, can you give a minimal reproducable example of data? What kind of model are you running? For within-models, time invariant variables will drop out (e.g. age or gender). For factor variables, you will have one variable drop out as baseline...

Comment: Many thanks. Somehow the problem was solved. It's wired :).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `keep` instead. Then you select the variables you want to display instead. Then your code would become:

```
stargazer(modeltt,modelintt,modelintt1,modelintt2,modelintt3, 
          title = "Panel data with averaged climate variables part two",
          model.names = F, object.names = F, dep.var.caption = "Yield", 
          dep.var.labels.include = F,
          keep =  c("first variable you want to keep", "second variable", "and so on"),             
          column.labels = c("Only Ozone","Ozone and SPEI","Ozone and tem", 
          "Ozone and preci","All together"),
          dep.var.labels = "Yield", digits = 3,
          align = T, no.space = T, column.sep.width = "3pt", 
          omit.stat = "f", header = F)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.